# The following code doesnt work

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8.1, capture

I copied the following code from here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-Store-81-vs-25c80c2a#content

```
MediaCapture captureManager;
    async private void InitCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync();
    }

    async private void StartCapturePreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        capturePreview.Source = captureManager;
        await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
    }

    async private void StopCapturePreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await captureManager.StopPreviewAsync();
    }

    async private void CapturePhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

        // create storage file in local app storage 
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
            "TestPhoto.jpg",
            CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        // take photo 
        await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);

        // Get photo as a BitmapImage 
        BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));

        // imagePreivew is a <Image> object defined in XAML 
        imagePreview.Source = bmpImage;
    }
```

When I try running it capturePreview is not defined. I removed that line and i get two exceptions:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Do you know the problem?
Windows phone 8.1 RT app

edit: the same code can also be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you add the stack trace for the exceptions?

Comment: Did you correct a spelling mistake by some chance?
In the link you sent the code calls the control "imagePreivew" yet in your code you have posted you call it "imagePreview". If you've changed the name in the code behind you need to change it in the XAML as well.

Comment: yes, image preview is just an image created in the XAML by me. the code was copied without the xaml.

Comment: The exception seems to be thrown in the line:

'await captureManager.InitializeAsync()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an exception in a different page and when I called this Frame that exception rose, it had nothing to do with this actual code.